# Check Whether Internet Connection is available or not?

Tags: android

I am working on online app. [Problem] when internet is down or not available it gives me error [Force close], I tried to handle using broadCast Receiver but not meet exact solution, looking for better solution.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    NetworkInfo info = intent
            .getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

    if (null != info) {

        String state = info.getState().toString();

        if (state.equalsIgnoreCase("CONNECTED")) {
            SplashScreen.isWiFiConnected = true;
            Log.i("isWifiConnected", "=================TRUE");
        } else {
            SplashScreen.isWiFiConnected = false;
            Log.i("isWifiConnected", "=================FALSE");
        }

    }

}

}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
static String data = null;
private static HttpPost httppost;
private static HttpParams httpParameters;
private static int timeoutConnection = 30000;
private static HttpClient httpclient = null;
private static HttpResponse response = null;
private static int responseCode=0;
public static ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager;
public static NetworkInfo mNetworkInfo;
public static boolean isNetError=false;

/** Post Http data and returns final string and status on network */

public static void postHttp(String Url, Activity mActivity) {
try {
    isNetError=false;

    mConnectivityManager= (ConnectivityManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    mNetworkInfo = mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (mNetworkInfo != null && mNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())
    {
        httppost = new HttpPost(Url);
        httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", "some Text"));


        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

    }
    else
        isNetError=true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        isNetError=true;
        }

   if (responseCode == 200)
   {
        isNetError=false;
        System.out.println("final..." + data);
        }
        else
            isNetError=true;
    }
```

call this method in your doInBackground() of asyntask, and onPostExecute() check isNetError value and as mentioned in other answer of adding permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

```
if(isNetError)
//No internet 
else
//do your stuff
```

Comment: He just describe a problem regarding check network availability

Comment: i think you had not seen this line SplashScreen.isWiFiConnected = false;

Answer (score 4):

Just use this function to check whether the Internet connection is available or not:

```
/**
   * Checks if the device has Internet connection.
   * 
   * @return <code>true</code> if the phone is connected to the Internet.
   */
    public static boolean checkNetworkConnection(Context context)
    {
        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        
        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi =connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile =connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        
        if(wifi.isAvailable()||mobile.isAvailable())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

### Note:

Don't forget to add permission inside the AndroidManifest.xml file: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: You need to use

if(wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting() ||mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {

instead of isAvailable(), otherwise it would always return true

Comment: sorry i didn't update it, but you can check updates at: [Android – check Internet connection](http://www.technotalkative.com/?p=1704), Thanx

Answer (score 0):

A valid network connection does not necessarily mean you can access the Internet, and the OP was asking for ways to check the availability of an **Internet Connection**. Some WiFi networks might require users to open a browser and go through some kind of authorization before allowing Internet access, so just checking for a valid WiFi connection is not sufficient in this case.

A naive approach to checking for raw connectivity *without*  creating a GET/POST connection would be:

```
private boolean isConnected() {

    try {
        InetAddress.getByName("google.com");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**WARNING1**:
Having done some testing I must warn that the code above *DOES NOT REALLY WORK* even if it appears so the first couple of times.

The code attempts to resolve a host name that is not already in the DNS cache, so once a successful lookup has been cached the code will continue returning true even if the host is *not reachable anymore* since all modern OS's do DNS caching.

**BUT**... On Android the *[InetAddress](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html)* class has an additional method that is not found in the standard JavaSE - ***[InetAddress.isReachable (int timeout)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29)*** which according to javadocs:

"Tries to reach this InetAddress. This method first tries to use ICMP (ICMP ECHO REQUEST), falling back to a TCP connection on port 7 (Echo) of the remote host."

So a possible fix to the code above would be

```
InetAddress.getByName("google.com").isReachable(5000);
```

In cases when ICMP packets are blocked the only reliable way to check reachability would be to create a real connection to your host either via *[URLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html)*, *[HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)*,  *[Socket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html)* or anything in between.