# ListView cookie questions

Tags: android, caching, cookies, android-listview

Below is my code to populate a ListView from my web service.

1. How can I set and get this ListView from cookies? (There`s an example on my code)
2. Let`s say I have a button that will refresh this list, how to handle it?
3. How to handle if the user is connected to internet or not?

I basically want to know how to manage a ListView that is populated from a WebService.

```
public class EventsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("user_id", "1");

        BloompItClient.get("get_events", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {                
                JSONObject jsonResponse;
                try {
                    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                    try {
                        String state = jsonResponse.getString("state");

                        if (state.equals("1")) {
                            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                            JSONArray events = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("events");

                            for (int i = 0; i < events.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject currentEvent = events.getJSONObject(i);
                                HashMap<String, String> eventMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                eventMap.put("college", currentEvent.getString("college_username"));
                                eventMap.put("author", currentEvent.getString("user_username"));
                                eventMap.put("title", currentEvent.getString("title"));                                                     
                                eventMap.put("date", currentEvent.getString("date"));

                                eventsList.add(eventMap);
                            }

                            ListView eventsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.events);
                            EventsListAdapter eventsListAdapter = new EventsListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), eventsList);

                            // testing cookies

                            AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();

                            PersistentCookieStore persistentCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(getApplicationContext());
                            asyncHttpClient.setCookieStore(persistentCookieStore);

                            BasicClientCookie baseClientCookie = new BasicClientCookie("cookiesare", "awesome");
                            baseClientCookie.setVersion(1);
                            baseClientCookie.setDomain("it.bloomp");
                            baseClientCookie.setPath("/");
                            persistentCookieStore.addCookie(baseClientCookie);

                            List<Cookie> cookieList = persistentCookieStore.getCookies();

                            for (int i = 0; i < cookieList.size(); i++) {
                                System.out.println(cookieList.toString());
                            }

                            // testing cookies end

                            eventsListView.setAdapter(eventsListAdapter);
                        } else {

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        });
    }

    public void getEvents() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: The easiest way to add your code to your question here is to copy & paste, then highlight your code again and press ctrl-k. Viola, properly indented code on the same page as your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer your questions in reverse.

> How to handle if the user is connected to internet or not?

If this is no locally saved data, then without an internet connection there is nothing you can do.  You can prompt the user if they want to activate WiFi or Data Connectivity (if neither of them are active already).

[Check Whether Internet Connection is available or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8018396/1267661)

> Let`s say I have a button that will refresh this list, how to handle it?

If it makes sense to store your data locally, then simply call notifyDataSetChanged() on your Adapter. Otherwise requery your server and check for new or modified entries.

> How can I set and get this ListView from cookies?

Assuming that your example works, since you haven't posted any logcat errors, it is quite simple to move data in and out of cookies; use setAttribute() and getAttribute(). Really you can use any form of data storage: SQLite database, text file, etc. to handle the information that you have gathered and parsed through your JSONArray.

**Addition**

The easiest way to loop through your List is with the built-in iterator:

```
for(Cookie cookie : cookieList) {
    if(cookie.getAttribute("college_username").equals("Brown")) {
        // check more attributes or do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Understood. I`m looping trought all cookies, how can I get a certain cookie?

List<Cookie> cookieList = persistentCookieStore.getCookies();
                 
       for (int i = 0; i < cookieList.size(); i++) {
           System.out.println(cookieList.toString());
          }

Comment: How are you distinguishing one cookie from another? Creating a cookie for each event seems inefficient, but I've added an update.